# Find JSON values return as strings

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to read the JSON `data` to find how many instances each trait_type's `value` appears for each `nth` `edition` and send the value to the `HTML` table as a string with the trait_type value's `ID`. The `filter` function currently returns 0 for each value.

```js
var data = [
  {
    edition: 1,
    attributes: [
      {
        trait_type: "hair",
        value: "mullet"
      },
      {
        trait_type: "hat",
        value: "cap"
      }
    ]
  }
];
var mullet = data.filter(function (d) {
    return d.value === "mullet";
  }).length,
  cap = data.filter(function (d) {
    return d.value === "cap";
  }).length;

document.getElementById("mullet").innerText = mullet;
document.getElementById("cap").innerText = cap;
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Hair?</dt>
  <dd id="mullet"></dd>
  <dt>Hat?</dt>
  <dd id="cap"></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: The array with the properties you're looking for is in the `.attributes`

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to filter it deeper, currently you are just looking at the top layer of data so only the attributes key exists and the value key doesn't exist on
`{ edition: 1, attributes: []}`
It only exists on the attributes array inside your data
So what you need to do is to go one layer deeper, in your filter function. Like so:

```
function filterDataFor(type) {
 const result= data.filter(
({ attributes })=> attributes
    .filter(({value})=> value ===  type)
)
  return result.length
}
  let mullet = filterDataFor('mullet')
  let cap = filterDataFor('cap')

document.getElementById("mullet").innerText = mullet;
document.getElementById("cap").innerText = cap
```

Comment: I think this just finds how many instances there are. It doesn't actually read the value